# Which status code works for which type of exception in c# webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am working in webapi2 I need to know which status code works for which exception type. I have found some status code for some exception type. But I need complete exception versus http status code list.

```
if (ex.GetType() == typeof(NotImplementedException))
            {
                _exception = new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented, ex.Message));

            }
            else if (ex.GetType() == typeof(NullReferenceException))
            {
                _exception = new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.LengthRequired, ex.Message));

            }
            else if (ex.GetType() == typeof(OutOfMemoryException))
            {
                _exception = new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType, ex.Message));

            }
            else if (ex.GetType() == typeof(OverflowException))
            {
                _exception = new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.RequestEntityTooLarge, ex.Message));

            }
            else if (ex.GetType() == typeof(StackOverflowException))
            {
                _exception = new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.RequestEntityTooLarge, ex.Message));

            }
            else if (ex.GetType() == typeof(TypeInitializationException))
            {
                _exception = new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, ex.Message));

            }
            else if (ex.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
            {
                _exception = new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message));

            }
```

Comment: Is this what you need? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: There is NO one-to-one mapping between .NET exception and HTTP Status code. They are two different technologies / things. Most exceptions should be 500 - Server Error. PLUS, you don't want to leak too much detail to your clients, who knows what information they might use against you in an attack!

Comment: @David, you are right. I guess you may realize my problem.

Comment: Also, use `is` instead of the whole `GetType()` comparing. Just use `ex is NotImplementedException`. It's much cleaner.

Comment: But I need complete list.

Comment: As Belogix said there is no mapping. You have to come up with your own.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to map .NET exceptions to HTTP status codes is not possible. I have seen `NotAcceptable` being used because the developer seemed to think that the request was "not acceptable" when in fact `NotAcceptable` (406) is used in content negotation, and your code maps `OverflowException` to `RequestEntityTooLarge` (413). This informs the client that the request that was sent was too large for the server when in fact the overflow on the server clearly is an `InternalServerError` (500).

Simply map all your errors to `BadRequest` (400), `Forbidden` (403) and `InternalServerError` (500) (and perhaps a few other suitable status codes) but do not change the meaning of the status codes - they are part of the HTTP standard.

You are free to write detailed about the error in the content of the message which you also are doing in your code.